# how do I add multiple postman collections to 1 Github repo?

Tags: api, github, postman, integration

Created several collections for company API test.

Trying to add them to a GitHub repo using postman GitHub integrations.

When I'm trying to select a collection to add to the repo, it only lets me select 1 collection, not all of them.

Is it possible to add all of them to 1 repo?

If so, how do I?

Comment: it is possible.